# Media player in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to load a video in JavaFX. When I click to load the page containing the video however I get the error:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 5: file:\C:\Users\Lynsey\Documents\My CamStudio Videos\1.flv

Here's the code I use to try and load the media

```
Media media = new Media("file:\\C:\\Users\\Lynsey\\Documents\\My CamStudio Videos\\1.flv");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
    videoPane.getChildren().add(view);
    player.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have whitespace in a URL.

The "quick and dirty" fix (I think) is

```
Media media = new Media("file:\\C:\\Users\\Lynsey\\Documents\\My%20CamStudio%20Videos\\1.flv");
```

A better fix is

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Lynsey\\Documents\\My CamStudio Videos\\1.flv");
// check file exists:
if (file.exists()) {
    Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
} else {
    System.out.println("file does not exist");
}
```

You can use a `java.nio.Path` instead of the `java.io.File` if you prefer. I tend just to use `File` with JavaFX as the built-in `FileChooser` returns `File`s and not `Path`s.

If the file exists and it still fails, then it's likely the video format is not compatible. The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm#JFXMD101) lists the currently supported formats.

Comment: I took the whitespace out of the actual file name and its still giving me the same error. The second fix you posted doesn't work as there a problem with the media line..it says media can't be converted to String or something

Comment: Updated second version.

Comment: I've tried this and now I'm no longer getting that error. The page is loading but with no video and its printing that the file does not exist but it does and its in that location. any ideas?

Comment: Remove the file: protocol from the File constructor. Sorry for the incremental answer; it's been a while since I used Windows and I forget the vagaries of the file naming.

Comment: Done that. Its no longer saying the file is not found but the content is just not loading or playing when the page loads. The page remains blank

Comment: Note that File is a legacy API since Java SE 7. Use java.nio.file.Path.

Comment: Got it. I had to convert it to mp4 and then it worked

Comment: FLV containers are only [supported media](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) in Java 8 with the rare VP6 encoding.  Probably your FLV file was not VP6 encoded, which is likely why you needed to do the mp4 conversion in order to allow your video to play.